# functional typescript error messages help for clean architecture project

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, functional-programming

I am getting my feet wet in functional programming using typescript and am using it for a new project but am running into a few roadblocks.  For the code below, I am using it for a clean architecture model but am receiving typescript errors but am not sure where it is telling me the problem lies.  Any help in understanding how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

1. Type 'TaskEither<Error, void>' is not assignable to type 'TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>'.

- Where could the void be coming from and how should I go about fixing it?

2. Argument of type '(country: string) => TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(b: Either<DomainError, string>) => TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>'.
   Types of parameters 'country' and 'b' are incompatible.

- Where is the "b: Either<DomainError, string>" coming from and how should I go about fixing it?

The complete error messages are listed below the code section.

```
  import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';
  import { Option } from "fp-ts/Option";
  import { some } from "fp-ts/Option";
  import { Either } from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
  import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
  import { TaskEither, left, right, chain, fromEither } from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither';

  type NotFoundError = { kind: string; message: string };
  type DomainError = { kind: string, message: string };



  type UserRepository = {
    retrieveUsers: (page: number) => (name: string) => (street: string) => (city: string) => (state: string) => (zipCode: string) => (country: string) => TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>;
  }

  export const makeUserRepository = (client: Client): UserRepository => {
    const retrieveUsers = (page) => (name) => (street) => (city) => (state) => (zipCode) => (country): TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>> => tryCatch(
        async () => {
            let queryString = '';
            let paramList = [];
            let queryScenarios = [];
            let counter = 0;

            queryString += `
            SELECT c."name", a."userId", a."companyId", a."city", a."state", a."zipCode", a."street", a."country"
            FROM profile."User" a INNER JOIN profile."Company" c ON (a."companyId" = c."companyId")
          `;

            if (name && name.length > 0) {
                queryScenarios.push('(c.name like %$' + (++counter) + '%)');
                paramList.push(name);
            }

            if (street && street.length > 0) {
                queryScenarios.push('a."street" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
                paramList.push(street);
            }

            if (city && city.length > 0) {
                queryScenarios.push('a."city" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
                paramList.push(city);
            }

            if (state && state.length > 0) {
                queryScenarios.push('a."state" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
                paramList.push(state);
            }

            if (zipCode && zipCode.length > 0) {
                queryScenarios.push('a."zipCode" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
                paramList.push(zipCode);
            }

            if (country && country.length > 0) {
                queryScenarios.push('a."country" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
                paramList.push(country);
            }

            queryString += " LIMIT $" + (++counter) + " OFFSET $" + (++counter);
            paramList.push((isValidNumber(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) ? parseInt(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) : 0));
            paramList.push((isValidNumber(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) ? parseInt(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) : 0) * (page - 1));

            const result: QueryResult<User> = await client.query(queryString, paramList);
            return result.rows.length > 0 ? some(result.rows) : none;
        },
        (reason) => new Error(String(reason))
    );

    return {
        retrieveUsers
    }
}


const validatePageNameFields = (page: number) => (name: string) => (street: string) => (city: string) => (state: string) => (zipCode: string) => (country: string): Either<DomainError, string> => {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        name: Joi.string().min(4).max(50).allow(null),
        page: Joi.number().required(),
        street: Joi.string().min(8).max(75).allow(null),
        city: Joi.string().min(1).max(50).allow(null),
        state: Joi.string().min(1).max(50).allow(null),
        zipCode: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).allow(null),
        country: Joi.string().min(5).max(25).allow(null),
    });

    let {error} = schema.validateAsync({page, name, street, city, state, zipCode, country});
    if (error && error.length > 0)
        return E.left({ kind: 'ValidationError', message: error });

    return E.right(country);
};

type UserInteractor = {
    retrieveUserList: (page: number) => (name: string) => (street: string) => (city: string) => (state: string) => (zipCode: string) => (country: string) => TaskEither<Error | NotFoundError, Option<User[]>>;
};

export const makeUserInteractor = (repository: ReturnType<typeof makeUserRepository>): UserInteractor => {
    const retrieveUserList = (page) => (name) => (street) => (city) => (state) => (zipCode) => (country): TaskEither<Error | NotFoundError, Option<User[]>> => {
        return pipe(
            country,
            validatePageNameFields(page)(name)(street)(city)(state)(zipCode),
            repository.retrieveUsers(page)(name)(street)(city)(state)(zipCode),
            chain((maybeUser) => {
                if (maybeUser._tag === 'None') {
                    return left({ kind: 'NotFoundError', message: 'User not found.' });
                }
                return right(some(maybeUser.value));
            })
        );
    };
}


error TS2322: Type 'TaskEither<Error, void>' is not assignable to type 'TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Option<User[]>'.

const retrieveUsers = (page) => (name) => (street) => (city) => (state) => (zipCode) => (country): TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>> => tryCatch(
~~~~~~~~~
    async () => {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
(reason) => new Error(String(reason))
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    );
~~~~~


error TS2345: Argument of type '(country: string) => TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(b: Either<DomainError, string>) => TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>>'.
Types of parameters 'country' and 'b' are incompatible.
Type 'Either<DomainError, string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'Right<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.

repository.retrieveUsers(page)(name)(street)(city)(state)(zipCode),
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: I removed tag [tag:functional-dependencies] because it is a technical term not relevant here. (Turns up in DBs/SQL & Haskell.)

Comment: Hope to never work with such codebase, worst practise "functional style" programming with, attention, classes .
As for the question - going to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and sharing here a link to your code with reproducible errors would help to answer it a lot.

Comment: @Alexander I am definitely a novice to "functional style" and am working to learn it.  If you have any online resources, links, books to suggest, etc. that might aid in improving my knowledge in it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is to change as following

1.the retrieveUsers function returning void instead of Option<User[]>. This is because the tryCatch function is not returning a value
2. the validatePageNameFields function returning Either<DomainError, string> instead of string

```
   const retrieveUsers = (page) => (name) => (street) => (city) => (state) => (zipCode) => (country): TaskEither<Error, Option<User[]>> => tryCatch(
    async () => {
        let queryString = '';
        let paramList = [];
        let queryScenarios = [];
        let counter = 0;

        queryString += `
        SELECT c."name", a."userId", a."companyId", a."city", a."state", a."zipCode", a."street", a."country"
        FROM profile."User" a INNER JOIN profile."Company" c ON (a."companyId" = c."companyId")
      `;

        if (name && name.length > 0) {
            queryScenarios.push('(c.name like %$' + (++counter) + '%)');
            paramList.push(name);
        }

        if (street && street.length > 0) {
            queryScenarios.push('a."street" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
            paramList.push(street);
        }

        if (city && city.length > 0) {
            queryScenarios.push('a."city" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
            paramList.push(city);
        }

        if (state && state.length > 0) {
            queryScenarios.push('a."state" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
            paramList.push(state);
        }

        if (zipCode && zipCode.length > 0) {
            queryScenarios.push('a."zipCode" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
            paramList.push(zipCode);
        }

        if (country && country.length > 0) {
            queryScenarios.push('a."country" like %$' + (++counter) + '%');
            paramList.push(country);
        }

        queryString += " LIMIT $" + (++counter) + " OFFSET $" + (++counter);
        paramList.push((isValidNumber(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) ? parseInt(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) : 0));
        paramList.push((isValidNumber(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) ? parseInt(process.env.MAX_PAGE_SIZE) : 0) * (page - 1));

        const result: QueryResult<User> = await client.query(queryString, paramList);
        return result.rows.length > 0 ? some(result.rows) : none;
    },
    (reason) => new Error(String(reason))
);

const validatePageNameFields = async (page: number) => (name: string) => (street: string) => (city: string) => (state: string) => (zipCode: string) => (country: string): Either<DomainError, string> => {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        name: Joi.string().min(4).max(50).allow(null),
        page: Joi.number().required(),
        street: Joi.string().min(8).max(75).allow(null),
        city: Joi.string().min(1).max(50).allow(null),
        state: Joi.string().min(1).max(50).allow(null),
        zipCode: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).allow(null),
        country: Joi.string().min(5).max(25).allow(null),
    });

    let {error} = await schema.validateAsync({page, name, street, city, state, zipCode, country});
    if (error && error.length > 0)
        return E.left({ kind: 'ValidationError', message: error });

    return E.right(country);
};
```

Comment: I am still receiving the errors.  One question seems to be, how should I arrange the pipe in the interactor to eliminate the type errors. With the types I have provided, what is causing the various functions to not pass data to one another?